# Minor theme glitch in Chrome at non-100% zoom

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In Google Chrome, when zoomed in or out, the homepage looks like this:

[image: Lines above the tabs]

Notice the lines above the main tabs. They seem to have wrapped around from the bottom. This happens at almost every zoom-level apart from 100%.

Obviously it's a minor issue, but if it happens to be easy to fix, that'd be nice.

Comment: I can also reproduce this on Safari 5.0.3 on every zoom level *except* 100%, the next zoom level in, and 4 zoom levels in.

Comment: Closing because we've changed to a new design (which may or may not have the same issue, please file again)

Comment: New theme appears to have fixed this issue!

Answer (score 3):

I think it's normal for minor rendering precision issues to sneak in, for certain web browser engines, as you zoom in and out.

Comment: the important words being "rendering precision issues" -- this is definitely a browser issue (treating `background-position-y: -56px;` as something like `background-position-y: -55.6px;`)